# How do I use a UDF in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, user-defined-functions

I am converting an Access DB to MySQL and have got to the stage where I need to convert Access functions in a global module (.bas) file to MySQL. The original code makes calls to the functions in the 'SELECT' statement part so I want to create the equivalent code and call them in the SELECT within PHP.

I don't need to use these functions anywhere else since they are pretty specific to this project so I want to call them from the script/code block that I'm writing in PHP PDO where I query the MySQL tables (SELECT, FROM). No examples explain this; most assume you wish to create a stored procedure. Where do I write these callable UDF's? - I'm using my own classes and methods file.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html – *"For the UDF mechanism to work, functions must be written in C or C++ and your operating system must support dynamic loading."* – This happens at a decidedly different level than [tag:php] or SQL…!?

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way. Try making a seperation of concerns. Have the functionality in php. Have the storage in sql. So make php functions that execute the queries needed.

Comment: I should have made it clearer sorry - i see examples where a User defined function can be called similar to an internal mysql function within your select statement. @shawns answer below shows the function code im going to implement but where do i write the function called hello() ?? in the same file, in the same code block ?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use MySQL FUNCTION.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html

There are more complex examples in the comments, you can refer to them.

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
END
//

delimiter ;
SELECT hello('world');
+----------------+
| hello('world') |
+----------------+
| Hello, world!  |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks shawn where do i put this function ?? i can figure out how to convert the functions but where would i write the function hello() so its callable in my SELECT wriiten in PHP/PDO mysql? Do i put this in the same code block

Comment: Put it in MySQL. You can use some MySQL GUI tools to help you to edit the functions in MySQL.